# Run shell script when I use the Voice Assistant button on my headset (MacOS)

Tags: terminal, bluetooth, automation, headphones, siri

#### Background:

I would like to use the Voice Assistant button on my Headset to speak the title of the song that is currently playing. I would like to just have the button trigger terminal command located in a file on my hard drive, and do not want to use third-party software. Is this even possible? If so, how do I go about it?

#### My specific hardware is:

MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015) running MacOS Monterey 12.6.6

WF-1000XM3 Bluetooth earbuds. (You access voice assistant by holding down the button on the right ear.)

After a lot of Google Searching, I was not able to find anything on the topic, so my guess is that you can't do it, but anybody who knows anything otherwise is much appreciated.

Comment: Ok. You want these features.  What research have have you done to see if this is all n possible?  Remember, we don’t write code or scrips on demand

Comment: I just did a **lot** of Google Searching, but was not able to find anything relating to the topic at all. My guess is that it is not possible, but I still wanted to see if anyone here has any ideas on how to go about it.